# ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX's multicol

Tags: context, multicol, multicolumn

Is there a ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX's multicol environment?

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\end{multicols}
```

I couldn't find anything with a quick Google search and am not convinced I'll find anything in the ConTeX wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ConTeXt has the `\startcolumns`…`\stopcolumns` construct which works quite similar to its LaTeX counterpart:

```
\startcolumns[n=3]
  Text text text text …
\stopcolumns
```

There are a few options beyond `n` such as `rule` to draw a vertical rule between the columns, `distance` setting the distance between columns, `balance` to toggle column balancing, and more.

ConTeXt also has the `\startcolumnset`…`\stopcolumnset` construct enabling  advanced multicolumn layouts:

```
\definecolumnset[ThreeeCols][n=3]
…
\startcolumnset [ThreeeCols]
  \title{Dummy text title}
  Text text text text …
\stopcolumnset
```

There is more information on that at the [ConTeXt Garden wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Category:Command/Columns).